# 301 Redirects (htaccess) with exclude conditions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I'm currently moving a site (shop) to a new domain and putting in its place a non-shop version (made in wordpress) of the site. The aim is for most of the urls to redirect to the new domain except the few pages that the new site has. I've found other posts on stackoverflow but unfortunately I can't seem to get it working. Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks Jason.

The urls I need to exclude are:
/ (Homepage)
/news and its posts /news/post-name
/products and its posts /products/post-name
/offers and its posts /offers/post-name
/our-philosophy
/our-team
/our-dream

Here's what I  tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

#Home
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/

#News
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news(.*)

#Products
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/products(.*)

#Offers
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/offers(.*)

#Philosophy
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/our-philosophy(.*)

#Team
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/our-team(.*)

#Dream
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/our-dream(.*)

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.cotswold-fayre.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>



# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: This should be on serverfault, it's not programming related..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try adding the following to your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

#Home: Exclude the home Page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ [OR]

#News: exclude anything that starts with /news, /products etc
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(news|products|offers|our-philosophy|our-team|our-dream) [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.cotswold-fayre.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```